# Building Create React App for production in Docker Container

Tags: reactjs, docker, deployment, create-react-app

I am having a problem with creating a docker image for my CRA application. Here is my Dockerfile that I use for the production environment:

```
# base image
FROM node:10.13.0
# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn

COPY . ./
# RUN yarn cache clean 
RUN yarn build

# Stage 2 - the production environment
FROM nginx:latest
# COPY build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./build /var/www
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

The `docker build` process runs successfully up to the 8th step where it returns the following error: `Step 8/11 : COPY ./build /var/www lstat build: no such file or directory`

From my understanding the error tells me that the build folder was not created after all, therefore it cannot be moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `Dockerfile` uses [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/). 8th step - `COPY ./build /var/www` fails because, it is trying to copy `build` directory from nginx image (2nd stage, and not from the 1st stage where `yarn build` is run) to `/var/www`, which doesn't exist.

To get it working, specify that `build` directory should be copied from the first stage (where `yarn build` is run). For this, make the following changes:

1. Name the base stage by changing the 1st line to `FROM node:10.13.0 AS base` (can use any name instead of `base` here).
2. Change `COPY ./build /var/www` to `COPY --from=base ./build /var/www` to say that we want to copy `build` directory from 1st stage and not from the 2nd stage.

Comment: Thanks @Bless. What you mentioned in your answer was the major part of the fix for my issue. The other problem that I had was the docker version which was not supporting the `AS` keyword and the `--from` flag. Therefore I had to apply your suggestion and update the docker.